# How to integrate Google Assistant into Flutter android app

Tags: android, flutter, google-assistant

I am writing a flutter application for android which must allow Google Assistant to open the app to pages for certain features.

I have looked at many examples online, including Google's codelabs and https://fidev.io/ok-google-flutter/ (which is now out of date as the methods used have been depricated). Furthermore, the Google Assistant Plugin for android studio throws an exception whenever I try to open it (for which I have tried many versions of the plugin and many versions of android studio to no success).

Does anyone know of any methods to a) integrate flutter android apps with google assistant and b) test that the plugin works?